# JSON if new object is created update list with new object

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am not so sure if this is even possible.(i just started learning JSON). Now on to the question:

I am working on a website and android app with comments and such, client wants instant notifications like facebook on the site.

What i am trying to do is to have in my php file a block where ex: A new comment is posted, comment is added to database succesfully, complete the front end update for user etc(all done), then if comment is successfully added, insert new object into JSON document with comment and details.

That way i can just use ajax to continually poll the .JSON file instead of the database(which should be faster me thinks), and when it sees an update it updates a list with the new update.

My problem is how do i append the updated object from json, and also what if there are 3 updates in that period, how do i print out just the 3 updates

Thanks so much, i know i don't have the code up, but all i need basically is how to display the newest objects in JSON

Comment: Why don't you just use PHP to emit the JSON?

Comment: @ExplosionPills that means i will keep polling the database, which will then print the JSON data, but i figured it'd be better to just keep going to a .JSON file rather than connect a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to keep track on what posts that should be considered as "new" for the user. But regardless of your json data structure, you can always get the last object by doing something like:

**your json file:**

```
[
    {
        "msg": "foo",
        "datestamp": 12345
    },
    {
        "msg": "bar",
        "datestamp": 12346
    }
]
```

**javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourjsonfile.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){

        var lastObject = data[data.length-1];
        alert(lastObject.msg);
    }
});
```

Hopefully this will get you on the right track. But as I mentioned earlier, you will need to have more advanced logic in order to know whats "new" for the user.

Comment: @Tunji Np, let me know if you have any questions